# Why does readMetadata() give me incorrect data?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, metadata-api, button-overrides

I have a script that uses the metadata API to update the 'New' and 'Edit' action overrides for Account so those actions navigate to a couple of custom VisualForce pages.

The script works. I can use setup->customize->Account->Buttons, Links, and Actions to see that the overrides now have the new type, content, and comments, and I can click the New and Edit buttons for Account and they do indeed redirect to my custom pages.

The problem is that when I use readMetadata on Account to programmatically check if the overrides are set, the metadata that is returned says that the type of the Edit actionOverride is 'Default' instead of 'Visualforce'. Why is it lying to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an 'Edit' action override on the OpportunityLineItem to a Visualforce page. This was configured via the UI rather than via the metadata API.

Performing a call to retrieve with a `RetrieveRequest` containing a `PackageTypeMembers` with:

- `name` = "CustomObject"
- `members` = ["OpportunityLineItem"]

Gives a package containing:

**package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>OpportunityLineItem</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>34.0</version>
</Package>
```

**objects/OpportunityLineItem.object**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <!-- ... -->
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>Delete</actionName>
        <type>Default</type>
    </actionOverrides>
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>Edit</actionName>
        <comment>Redirect the editing of XYZ to the ABC page.</comment>
        <content>XyzOliEditPageRedirect</content>
        <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
        <type>Visualforce</type>
    </actionOverrides>
    <!-- ... -->
</CustomObject>
```

So, in this case it does return the expected [ActionOveride](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/actionoverride.htm) via the CustomObject.

Note that the docs for [ActionOverrideType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/actionoverride.htm#filteroperation) states:

> *default*—The override uses a custom override provided by an installed
>   package. If there isn’t one available, the standard Salesforce
>   behavior is used.

So, either:

[image]

or, Salesforce is only partially lying to you about the nature of reality and will still find the Visualforce page even if the value is default.

See also:

- [How to retrieve action overrides?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/15675/102)

Comment: This *only* seems to happen on OpportunityLineItem Edit. This *one* override behaves badly every time I try to use the metadata API on it. And it's been that way for years. Someone really should look into it.

Comment: @sfdcfox So you see `default` rather than `visualforce` for the edit actionOverride on OpportunityLineItem? Did you configure yours via the metadata API or via the UI? I'm wondering if it is specific to how it was initially setup.

Comment: I can't get it to replicate right now, but I think it might be a cross-org deploy problem. We would do deployments where the error would say "unknown override ourpagename" instead of "OurPageName" (in other words, the API lower-cased the page name in the action override). Other times, I'm pretty sure it would retrieve as default. We had gotten in the habit of checking that setting after every deploy, "just in case."

Comment: @Neo, I believe, but can't verify, that it means it will continue to work even if it says the type is `default` rather than `visualforce`. The docs do state that this is specific to a managed package. I think that means the custom package setting will be used unless overridden specifically within the customers org.

Comment: It does seem to be using the override properly, but I perform a programmatic check so I  can indicate to the user that the override is already in place. This check doesn't work if the metadata I get back doesn't let me know where the action will direct the user.

Comment: @Neo, do you still get the content element back? If so, and the type is default, you may need to verify it against the available Visualforce pages to verify it is configured.

Comment: It turns out it was confused because I was testing in the same dev org in which I was developing the package. When I installed a beta version of my code on another org, it worked fine. In the end, I think it was reading the wrong metadata because of the session id. So what it told me was true...from a certain view. <obi-wan_ghost.gif>